# Excel VBA: Erase all rows that AREN'T duplicated

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

vba novice here.  I wrote a program that creates a new Excel file and copies over several rows of data based on search terms entered by a user.  If the user is searching for more than one string of text, he/she can select "or" or "and" between each string. So, if a user enters "Apples OR Pears" the program will output any data that has apples or has pears.  If the user enters "Apples AND pears" the program will output any data that contains both apples and pears.

I've figured out how to remove duplicate rows, but I want to figure out how to do the OPPOSITE.  I'd like to remove any rows that DON'T have duplicates.  I'd like to keep one copy of the rows that are duplicated one or more times.  For instance, if I had a one-column row reading:

```
Apples
Oranges
Pears
Apples
Cherries
Pears
```

I'd want the macro to delete rows such that the new list just reads:

```
Apples
Pears
```

I'd prefer to run the macro in a way that doesn't require copying over to multiple sheets.  This is because the code I'm trying to figure out will be used within a For loop, which may get complicated running multiple times.

Here's my code as it sits now. I've commented where I'd like to insert this section of code:

```
    Dim srchLen, myString As Integer
    Dim nxtRw As Long
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim c As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim wbSearchTool As Workbook
    Dim wbSearchResults As Workbook

    'Create and format a new workbook for search results
    Set wbSearchTool = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbSearchResults = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    wbSearchResults.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:C").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    wbSearchResults.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:R").WrapText = True
    wbSearchResults.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:R").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    wbSearchResults.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:R1").Font.Bold = True
    With wbSearchResults.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns("A:F").ColumnWidth = 10
        .Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 16.5
        .Columns("H:I").ColumnWidth = 35
        .Columns("J:R").ColumnWidth = 15
    End With

    'Copy Column Headings from Data
     wbSearchResults.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1) = wbSearchTool.Sheets("Data").Rows(1).Value

    'Determine length of Search Criteria Column from Search Sheet
        wbSearchTool.Activate
        srchLen = Sheets("Search").Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row

    'Loop through list in Search, Column C. As each value is
    'found in Data, Column F, copy it to the next row in Search Results

        If srchLen = 3 Then
        Else
        For myString = 4 To srchLen
            Set SearchRange = Sheets("Data").Range(Sheets("Search").Range("F" & myString).Value)
            With SearchRange
                Set c = .Find(Sheets("Search").Range("C" & myString), lookat:=xlPart)
                  If Not c Is Nothing Then
                   firstAddress = c.Address
                    Do
                      nxtRw = wbSearchResults.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                      wbSearchResults.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & nxtRw & ":R" & nxtRw) = wbSearchTool.Sheets("Data").Range("A" & c.Row & ":R" & c.Row).Value
                      Set c = .FindNext(c)
                    Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
                  End If
            End With

            'THIS IS WHERE I WANT CODE TO ONLY KEEP DUPLICATES!!!

        Next
        End If
```

Comment: Please rework the code sample to reduce it to only what is needed.

Comment: To be honest, this is the reduced code that I thought was relevant to try understanding what I was trying to do, haha.  This code currently works if someone searches with only "or" options. So if someone searches for "Apples OR Pears OR Oranges" than this code creates a new workbook, searches the data and copies over any rows that contain "apples," then searches the data and copies over any rows that contain "Pears", then "oranges."  In the end, in code you don't see here, I delete all the duplicates... therefore outputting one copy of each row that contains either apples, pears, or oranges.

Comment: However, if someone wants to search for "Apples AND Pears OR Oranges" then I need nested within the For loop shown, code that will output all rows containing apples, then output all rows containing pears, then only keep the rows that were duplicated (therefore containing both apples and pears), then output all rows containing oranges.

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding comments. Not all comments may be shown initially. By putting all relevant information in one place you make it easier to help you. Consider trimming your code down to a [mcve] --- cell formatting is just noise here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic example of how to isolate cells that are duplicated in a range. You can use the `Range.Resize` method to extend the copy range when setting the `Duplicates` variable.

In photo, `Column A` is the original data & `Column B` is the macro output.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub Dups()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim SearchRange As Range: Set SearchRange = ws.Range("A1:A6")
Dim CurrentCell As Range, Duplicates As Range

For Each CurrentCell In SearchRange
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SearchRange, CurrentCell) > 1 Then
        If Not Duplicates Is Nothing Then
            Set Duplicates = Union(Duplicates, CurrentCell)
        Else
            Set Duplicates = CurrentCell
        End If
    End If
Next CurrentCell

Duplicates.Copy ws.Range("B1")
ws.Range("B:B").RemoveDuplicates 1, xlNo

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this later.